# Proper conjugation in writing commands (to oneself)?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, conjugaison

I sometimes write to-do list items in French, and often find it hard to decide how to conjugate items.  E.g:

- Go to bed at 10 pm ->...
- se coucher a 10h?
- me coucher a 10h?
- coucher a 10h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the infinitive in a todo list. "go to bed" is better translated by the more idiomatic "*aller se coucher*" than "*aller au lit*". As *se coucher* is pronominal, the form will depend on who the todo list is directed to, e.g.:

Generic:

- *Se coucher à 10h.*

To yourself:

- *Me coucher à 10h.*

To one kid:

- *Te coucher à 10h.*

To several kids:

- *Vous coucher à 10h.*

Comment: ahaha! yes of course... will edit my question to reflect that.  In this case, you would use the 'generic' or first person?

Comment: If the todo list if for yourself, that would be *Me coucher à 10h* although *Coucher à 10h* or even *Coucher, 10h* would do it too.

Comment: @anon0909 You shouldn't edit your question, except to clarify what you're asking. This answer now doesn't fully make sense as it mentions a mistake you made, which has now been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the infinitive form, like Jiliagre explained:

- remplir le dossier pour la Sécu
- rendre son saladier à la voisine

You can also use the imperative:

- fais la vaisselle
- pense à sortir les poubelles
- surveille ton petit frère
- désamorcez la bombe du secteur 8
- empêchez les ennemis de rentrer dans la ville
- rassemblez cinq coquilles rouges et apportez-les à Tartempion avant la nuit

Note that it won't work if you are leaving a list of things for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For a personnal TODO list, I would use a more familiar expressions "Dodo". It assumes no one would read it but you.
A second point is how to say "10pm". If there may be any confusion, you should better say "22h" to remove any ambiguity.

> 22h: dodo
>   22h: (Aller) [me/se] coucher (kind of too serious in my opinion)

Dodo is familiar and gives a childhood connotation. When used between adults, it's used as a joke saying "let's stop adults stuff and go back to childhood to sleep".

Comment: @anon0909 haha, yeah, "dodo" is also a bird, but here, "dodo" means "to sleep". You may use "Je vais faire dodo", "Je vais au dodo", "j'ai fait un gros dodo". Indeed, I may be a little offtopic, since you are not asking for this particular task :)